# Perl - Unable to call java jar file

Tags: java, perl, jar, system

```
system("java -jar \"TRNDHTMLtoPDF.jar\" \"test.pdf\" \"c.txt\" ");
```

Above code used to run a java jar file from Perl (cgi) page. When I run it from command prompt, it working fine, but when i try to run from a page, nothing happened, no error and no output.

```
$result= `"java -jar \"TRNDHTMLtoPDF.jar\" \"test.pdf\" \"c.txt\" "`;
```

When I try to print the $result. it show empty. Seems like the jar not executed at all. How do I solve this? Please advice.

Comment: Do you need the double quotes just inside the back-ticks?

Comment: i even tried with and without double quotes, with and without back slash

Comment: What OS? If Linux, add `2>&1` at the end to also capture the `stderr`. Otherwise, Perl puts the error into `$!` variable, and exist status of the child into the `$?` variable. Checking  them is strongly advised, if you care about error handling.

Comment: does the os user that runs the web server have the necessary privileges to execute java ?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the character **'** at the beginning and at the end. No escape with **\** should be needed anymore.

Comment: Not helping, same thing. The JAR not executed at all